# Expected value of discrete uniform variable

Tags: statistics, expectation

I have a question regarding linear combinations/transformations in statistics. I'm quite sure the answer is relatively easy, but I can't seem to find a solution that corresponds to my solution manual.

The question is as follows:
Say X is a uniform random variable on the interval $]0,2[$. Assume the following random variable $Q=6X^2+3$. What is the expected value of $Q$?

I started out by transforming the equation for $Q$.
$$E[Q] = E[6X^2+3]$$
$$= 6E[X^2] +3$$
$$ = 6(E[X])^2 + 3 + \frac{1}{2}Var(X)*2$$
Using the following formula from my 'cheat sheet': $E[g(X)] \approx g(E[X]) + \frac{1}{2}Var(X)*g''(E[X])$

Now I'm kind of stuck because I'm not sure if this approach is correct.

Any tip would be very helpful! This was translated from Dutch to English, so keep in mind that there might be some errors regarding statistic jargon.

Comment: Uniform, discrete, and on the interval $(0,2)$? How does that even work?

Comment: I have another approach. Use The relation $E[X]^2=Var(X)+(E[X])^2$

Comment: @5xum Woops, discrete was not appropriate for this exercises. I mixed up two questions :)

Comment: @calculus So the last step would change to $=6[Var(X) + (E[X])^2] + 3$ ?

Comment: Why not compute directly $E(X^2)=\int_0^2x^2\frac12dx=\left.\frac16x^3\right|_0^2=\frac43$ hence $E(Q)=6E(X^2)+3=11$? Or are we supposed to consider that var$(X)$ is always simpler to compute / more elementary than $E(X^2)$? (It is not.)

Comment: @Did I was just coming here to answer that. I looked at it a little longer and eventually found that solution as well. 11 is indeed the correct expected value. You can post your comment as the answer and I'll accept it.